# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

So I'm just exporting a basic program with one library `tornadofx-1.7.11.jar` plus the standard Kotlin library. I've exported it fully using [this guide](http://karthicraghupathi.com/2016/07/10/creating-an-executable-jar-in-intellij-idea/). I tried running it in the command line, but received this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
at main.app.AppKt.main(app.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
```

I've looked up my issue [here](https://samebug.io/exceptions/574653/java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError/kotlinjvminternalintrinsics?soft=false), and it said that my error has to do with a broken class path. I have no idea what I'm doing with regards to class paths, but the guide mentioned earlier stated to just put the names of all jars. If you really want it, here's my class path: `tornadofx-1.7.11.jar`. Just that one line. I'm not sure if I should add more, but I did it like the example showed.

If needed, I'm running on Intellij IDEA version `2017.2.6.IC-172.4574.11`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the kotlin stdlib to the classpath to to run it from the command line.

Something like:

```
java --class-path tornadofx-1.7.11.jar stdlib.jar -jar myprogram.jar
```

Running it from InteliJ is simpler since it configures it on its own.

Comment: I've been running from Intellij to produce my project, but I'm trying to export it to run elsewhere. Where should I cd to before running this command?

Comment: Use absolute paths instead of those qvasy jar names, so it wouldn't matter

Comment: A hint: when running a program in InteliJ, it prints the execution command at the top of the terminal. Copy-paste it, and it must work from the root of your project

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "qvasy jar names", but I tried finding the execution command and got this: https://gist.github.com/fin444/ecd4302a17114407d49073c642d360e2. How do I know what is essential, and what is part of Intellij?

Comment: Use the same class path as in that command and it should work