# Paper minecraft plugin. Problems with CommandExecutor and PlayerEventListener

Tags: kotlin, minecraft

I cant figure out what the problem is I have tested to fix it many times but it does not work.

Code is written using Kotlin.

This is all my code.

Main function:
MyFirstPlugin.kt

```
package me.kotia.myfirstplugin

import me.kotia.myfirstplugin.commands.JumpCommand
import me.kotia.myfirstplugin.listeners.jumpListener
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin

class MyFirstPlugin : JavaPlugin() {
    override fun onEnable() {
        // Plugin startup logic
        logger.info("Loaded!")
        registerCommand()
        registerListener()
    }

    private  fun registerListener(){
        server.pluginManager.registerEvents(jumpListener(), this)
        logger.info("Listener succesfully registered")
    }

    private fun registerCommand(){
        getCommand("jump")?.setExecutor(JumpCommand())
        logger.info("Command succesfully registered")
    }

    override fun onDisable() {
        // Plugin shutdown logic
        logger.info("Unloaded!")
    }
}
```

Jump Event Listener:
jumpListener.kt

```
package me.kotia.myfirstplugin.listeners

import com.destroystokyo.paper.event.player.PlayerJumpEvent
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler
import org.bukkit.event.Listener
import java.util.EventListener

class jumpListener : Listener {

    @EventHandler
    public fun playerJumpEvent(event: PlayerJumpEvent){
        event.player.sendMessage("You have jumped!")
    }

}
```

Command Executer:
jumpCommand.kt

```
package me.kotia.myfirstplugin.commands

import net.kyori.adventure.text.Component
import net.kyori.adventure.text.format.TextColor
import org.bukkit.command.Command
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender
import org.bukkit.entity.Player
import org.bukkit.util.Vector
import org.objectweb.asm.Label


class JumpCommand : CommandExecutor {
    override fun onCommand(sender: CommandSender, command: Command, label: String, args: Array<out String>?): Boolean {
        if(sender is Player){
            if(sender.isOp){
                sender.sendMessage("Succes")
                sender.velocity = sender.velocity.add(Vector(0f, 5f, 0f))
            }
            else {
                sender.sendMessage(Component.text("You do not have permission to run this command").color(TextColor.color(255, 0, 0)))
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

plugin.yml

name: MyFirstPlugin
version: '${project.version}'
main: me.kotia.myfirstplugin.MyFirstPlugin
api-version: '1.19'
commands:
jump:
description: lounches player in air

Logs errors while I am jumping and trying to use my command

```
[11:18:59 ERROR]: Could not pass event PlayerJumpEvent to MyFirstPlugin v1.0-SNAPSHOT
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
        at me.kotia.myfirstplugin.listeners.jumpListener.playerJumpEvent(jumpListener.kt) ~[myfirstplugin.jar:?]
        at com.destroystokyo.paper.event.executor.asm.generated.GeneratedEventExecutor1.execute(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.EventExecutor$2.execute(EventExecutor.java:77) ~[paper-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at co.aikar.timings.TimedEventExecutor.execute(TimedEventExecutor.java:81) ~[paper-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:git-Paper-550]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:70) ~[paper-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperEventManager.callEvent(PaperEventManager.java:54) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-550]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperPluginManagerImpl.callEvent(PaperPluginManagerImpl.java:126) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-550]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:615) ~[paper-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.event.Event.callEvent(Event.java:45) ~[paper-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.network.ServerGamePacketListenerImpl.handleMovePlayer(ServerGamePacketListenerImpl.java:1516) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.network.protocol.game.ServerboundMovePlayerPacket.handle(ServerboundMovePlayerPacket.java:29) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.network.protocol.game.ServerboundMovePlayerPacket$Pos.handle(ServerboundMovePlayerPacket.java:66) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.network.protocol.PacketUtils.lambda$ensureRunningOnSameThread$0(PacketUtils.java:51) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.TickTask.run(TickTask.java:18) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-550]
        at net.minecraft.util.thread.BlockableEventLoop.doRunTask(BlockableEventLoop.java:153) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.util.thread.ReentrantBlockableEventLoop.doRunTask(ReentrantBlockableEventLoop.java:24) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.doRunTask(MinecraftServer.java:1342) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-550]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.d(MinecraftServer.java:197) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-550]
        at net.minecraft.util.thread.BlockableEventLoop.pollTask(BlockableEventLoop.java:126) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.pollTaskInternal(MinecraftServer.java:1319) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-550]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.pollTask(MinecraftServer.java:1312) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-550]
        at net.minecraft.util.thread.BlockableEventLoop.managedBlock(BlockableEventLoop.java:136) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.waitUntilNextTick(MinecraftServer.java:1290) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-550]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.runServer(MinecraftServer.java:1178) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-550]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:320) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-550]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.loadClass0(PluginClassLoader.java:183) ~[paper-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:150) ~[paper-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[?:?]
        ... 26 more
[11:19:06 INFO]: Arhimed228 issued server command: /jump
[11:19:06 ERROR]: null
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'jump' in plugin MyFirstPlugin v1.0-SNAPSHOT
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:47) ~[paper-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:155) ~[paper-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_19_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:929) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-550]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_19_R3.command.BukkitCommandWrapper.run(BukkitCommandWrapper.java:64) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-550]
        at com.mojang.brigadier.CommandDispatcher.execute(CommandDispatcher.java:264) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:?]
        at net.minecraft.commands.Commands.performCommand(Commands.java:322) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.commands.Commands.performCommand(Commands.java:306) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.network.ServerGamePacketListenerImpl.performChatCommand(ServerGamePacketListenerImpl.java:2297) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.network.ServerGamePacketListenerImpl.lambda$handleChatCommand$20(ServerGamePacketListenerImpl.java:2257) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.util.thread.BlockableEventLoop.lambda$submitAsync$0(BlockableEventLoop.java:59) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.TickTask.run(TickTask.java:18) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-550]
        at net.minecraft.util.thread.BlockableEventLoop.doRunTask(BlockableEventLoop.java:153) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.util.thread.ReentrantBlockableEventLoop.doRunTask(ReentrantBlockableEventLoop.java:24) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.doRunTask(MinecraftServer.java:1342) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-550]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.d(MinecraftServer.java:197) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-550]
        at net.minecraft.util.thread.BlockableEventLoop.pollTask(BlockableEventLoop.java:126) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.pollTaskInternal(MinecraftServer.java:1319) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-550]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.pollTask(MinecraftServer.java:1312) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-550]
        at net.minecraft.util.thread.BlockableEventLoop.managedBlock(BlockableEventLoop.java:136) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.waitUntilNextTick(MinecraftServer.java:1290) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-550]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.runServer(MinecraftServer.java:1178) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-550]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:320) ~[paper-1.19.4.jar:git-Paper-550]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
        at me.kotia.myfirstplugin.commands.jumpCommand.onCommand(jumpCommand.kt) ~[myfirstplugin.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) ~[paper-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.loadClass0(PluginClassLoader.java:183) ~[paper-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:150) ~[paper-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[?:?]
        at me.kotia.myfirstplugin.commands.jumpCommand.onCommand(jumpCommand.kt) ~[myfirstplugin.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) ~[paper-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        ... 23 more
```

Please help me understand what is wrong

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48052427/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-kotlin-jvm-internal-intrinsics) help ?